Contact-exportation exports all contacts instead of the results
In CiviCRM 5.72.2 (Joomla! 4.4.5), the contact export exports all contacts instead of all results. The alternative is to check all contacts of the search results and then check "Selection records only" to have the correct export.
Would this be a bug similar to the one described here: CiviCase Dashboard exports all cases instead of the results
